# Regex matching every single blank space

Tags: python, regex

I have this snippet regex part used in python:

```
(?<!\d)(\d??\d )?(hours|hour|hrs|hr|h)?( and |, )??(?<!\d)(\d??\d )?(minutes|minute|mins|min|m)?( and |, )?(?<!\d)(\d??\d )?(seconds|second|secs|sec|s)?
```

and I used regex101 to check my regex. It does not work how I wanted it to be. For some reason, when I press Enter to go to a new line, it has a match.

For example, I have 10 blank lines and regex101 found 10 matches, all matched at the beginning of each of the blank lines. Also, if I spammed space on a blank line, it matches every single blank space. The match information on the right side of the webpage didn't help because it only showed "null".

I have tried out both `\s` and literal space as shown in the regex code above, both has same results, 10 blank lines, 10 matches found. Couldn't think of why it matches every single blank space and a solution for it.

Full piece of regex:

```
(([0][0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-3])+?:([0][0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-9]|[4][0-9]|[5][0-9])+?:([0][0-9]|[1][0-9]|[2][0-9]|[3][0-9]|[4][0-9]|[5][0-9])+?)|((?<!\d|\w)(\d?\d\s)+?((hours)|(hour)|(hrs)|(hr)|(h)))?((\sand\s)|(,\s?))?((?<!\d|\w)(\d?\d\s)+?((minutes)|(minute)|(mins)|(min)|(m)))?((\sand\s)|(,\s?))?((?<!\d|\w)(\d?\d\s)+?((seconds)|(second)|(secs)|(sec)|(s)))?
```

If I typed "a", regex101 matched "" before the "a" and if I typed "5 hours", regex101 matched "5 hours" and "" after the "5 hours". In VS Code, if the user did not type anything, it fails to raise ValueError which then re-prompts the user for the time, same thing happens if the user types a space or random stuff like "asdfasdf". I have tried to catch it with:

```py
if test.group() == "":
    raise ValueError
```

It still fails to raise ValueError

My desired results for the snippet part includes (only 12 shown, a ton of combinations can be made) (Being matched as 1 entire group instead of 2 groups for "5 hours" and 8 groups for "5 hours, 5 minutes and 5 seconds"):

1. 5 hours, 5 minutes and 5 seconds
2. 5 hours and 5 minutes
3. 5 hours and 5 seconds
4. 5 hours, 5 minutes, 5 seconds
5. 5 hrs, 5 mins, 5 secs
6. 5 hours
7. 5 minutes
8. 5 seconds
9. 5 hours and 5 minutes
10. 5 minutes and 5 seconds
11. 5 minutes, 5 seconds
12. 5 hours, 5 seconds

Comment: It shouldn't match linebreaks but it might match the empty string '' as all the elements are optional

Comment: One (ugly) solution would be to explicitly `|` all the different possibilities: just hours, minutes or seconds, hours and minutes, hours and seconds, minutes and second, and all three.

Comment: @tobias_k That definitely could work, but I will leave it to the last resort since it is gonna be extremely long, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match:

- hours with `(\d+\s(?:hours|hour|hrs|hr|h))?`
- minutes with `(\d+\s(?:minutes|minute|mins|min|m))?`
- seconds with `(\d\s(?:seconds|second|secs|sec|s))?`
- separators with `(?:, | and )`

If you combine these together, you get the regex you were looking for:

```
(\d+\s(?:hours|hour|hrs|hr|h))?(?:, | and )?(\d+\s(?:minutes|minute|mins|min|m))?(?:, | and )?(\d\s(?:seconds|second|secs|sec|s))?
```

Then you need to extract your groups. You can check the following Python code:

```
import re

strings = [
    '5 hours, 5 minutes and 5 seconds',
    '5 hours and 5 minutes',
    '5 hours and 5 seconds',
    '5 hours, 5 minutes, 5 seconds',
    '5 hrs, 5 mins, 5 secs',
    '5 hours',
    '5 minutes',
    '5 seconds',
    '5 hours and 5 minutes',
    '5 minutes and 5 seconds',
    '5 minutes, 5 seconds',
    '5 hours, 5 seconds'
]

pattern = r'(\d+\s(?:hours|hour|hrs|hr|h))?(?:, | and )?(\d+\s(?:minutes|minute|mins|min|m))?(?:, | and )?(\d\s(?:seconds|second|secs|sec|s))?'

print([re.search(pattern, string).groups() for string in strings])

#for string in strings:
#    match = re.search(pattern, string)
#    if match:
#        print(match.group())
```

Check the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dBGahj/1) and the [python demo](https://www.online-python.com/ZsU72dbgap).

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it is certainly the closest one that I hoped for, but there is a problem that I've been trying to solve for a long time and your regex also has this problem. If the user just pressed enter when getting prompted for the time (literally inputting nothing and pressing enter, not even a space), there is somehow a match. I have tried `if test.group() == "":
raise ValueError` and it still does not raise a ValueError

Comment: In this case you need to handle it separately. Check the commented code on the updated demo.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking a ton, I just made a function instead of that "if" statement just to catch those and worked perfectly

Comment: The important part is that you avoid embedding that check inside the regex, which would mess it up. Checking for wrong inputs externally is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your regex allowing to match `nothing`. Let's rewrite your regex:

```
(?<!\d)(\d??\d )?(hours|hour|hrs|hr|h)?( and |, )??(?<!\d)(\d??\d )?(minutes|minute|mins|min|m)?( and |, )?(?<!\d)(\d??\d )?(seconds|second|secs|sec|s)?
```

Into something easier to look:

```
(...)?(...)?(...)??(...)? ...
```

Every group you are making it optional, so it allow to match `nothing` string.

Not just it matching empty lines, given a line of space          , it will create as many match as how many spaces there are.

Solution is instead of making `(...)?(...)?`, change it into altenate `(...)|(...)`

How to do it is depend on your requirement. You have given no requirement, so I'm giving an example based on my guess:

```
(?<!\d)(\d?\d )|(hours|hour|hrs|hr|h)|( and |, )??(?<!\d)(\d??\d )|(minutes|minute|mins|min|m)|( and |, )|(?<!\d)(\d??\d )|(seconds|second|secs|sec|s)
```

Comment: Not my downvote (the description of the problem is sound), but seeing the examples, it looks like every individual group _should_ be optional, but at least one of them should be present.

Comment: That's was my point. The question has given no requirement on how it should work. So we just guessing and give an example.

Comment: @namgold I have tried out your version of regex. Even though on regex101 it seems that it works and got what I wanted, in VS Code, if the user inputted "5 hours, 5 minutes and 5 seconds", only "5" is matched. Actually in regex101, it shows that "5 hours, 5 minutes and 5 seconds" has 8 matches instead of 1. The reason I typed out the desired results is because I want that entire string to be matched as 1 thing instead of 8

Comment: That would be another question. I don't have solution for it yet, but I have asked for it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75221690/regex-for-matching-string-with-optional-groups-with-separator)